# EventTime Window not firing

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to setup a streaming solution using `EventTime`. I will be consuming from Kafka. My data can be up to one minute delayed(So my WaterMark is delayed once minute) and out of order.  I have 30 second windows.  I have the following setup:

KafkaConsumer.scala

```
object KafkaConsumer {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
    val properties = getServerProperties
    val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[ObjectNode](getKafkaTopic, new JsonNodeDeserializationSchema, properties)
    consumer.setStartFromGroupOffsets()

    val stream = env.addSource(consumer)
      .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new WMAssigner)

    stream
      .keyBy { jsonEvent =>
        val key = jsonEvent.findValue("key").toString replaceAll("\"","")
        key.toString
      }
      .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30)))
      .process { new SessionWindowProcessor }
      .print
    env.execute("EventTime Test")
  }
}
```

WMAssigner.scala

```
class WMAssigner extends AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks[ObjectNode] {

  var currentMaxTimestamp: Long = 0
  var currentWaterMark: Long = 0

  override def extractTimestamp(element: ObjectNode, previousElementTimestamp: Long): Long = {
    val lStr = element.findValue("ts").toString replaceAll("\"", "")
    currentMaxTimestamp = if(currentMaxTimestamp > lStr.toLong) currentMaxTimestamp else lStr.toLong
    currentMaxTimestamp
  }

  override def getCurrentWatermark: Watermark = {
      currentWaterMark = if(currentMaxTimestamp - 60000 < 0) 0 else currentMaxTimestamp - 60000
      new Watermark(currentWaterMark)

  }
}
```

SessionWindowProcessor.scala

```
class SessionWindowProcessor extends ProcessWindowFunction[ObjectNode,Long,String,TimeWindow] {
  override def process(key: String, context: Context, elements: Iterable[ObjectNode], out: Collector[Long]): Unit = {
    println("Processing!")
    var maxVal: Long = 0
    elements.foreach( value => {
      val valStr = value.findValue("value").toString replaceAll("\"","")
      maxVal = if(valStr.toLong > maxVal) valStr.toLong else maxVal
    })
    out.collect(maxVal)
  }
}
```

Sample data:

```
"{\"ts\": 0,     \"key\": \"a\", \"value\": 0}",
"{\"ts\": 15000, \"key\": \"a\", \"value\": 1}",
"{\"ts\": 30000, \"key\": \"a\", \"value\": 2}",
"{\"ts\": 90001, \"key\": \"a\", \"value\": 3}"
```

I would expect after the fourth message comes in that my first window would trigger, with a value of `1` or `2`(I am unsure how inclusion works right now).  Unfortunately I am not even seeing the `println` in `SessionWindowProcessor.scala` firing.  Is there something I am doing wrong here that is causing my windowing to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, your `extractTimestamp()` method should be returning lStr.toLong, rather than currentMaxTimestamp. It makes sense that this method is keeping track of currentMaxTimestamp so that value can used for watermark generation, but the role of extractTimestamp is to provide to Flink the event time timestamp for each stream element.

However, I don't believe this explains why you are not seeing any output -- certainly not if your data is actually in-order by timestamp, as in the sample.

Also note that you could be using a [BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/event_timestamp_extractors.html#assigners-allowing-a-fixed-amount-of-lateness), which is a bit simpler to work with.

Comment: It was actually the `extractTimestamp` not returning `lStr` for some reason, once I returned `lStr.toLong` it worked as expected.  I did take your advice and used `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor`, it is a much simpler implementation as you said, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

How many partitions does your Kafka topic have? If it has more than one partition the problem is that Flink has to see for every partition a timestamp which exceeds `90000` in order to issue a watermark with the value `30000`. Thus, you either have to add some more data such that every partition has an element with a timestamp larger than `90000` or you set the number of partitions of the Kafka topic to `1`. Here is some more information about [watermarks and the Kafka connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-and-timestamp-extractionwatermark-emission).

Comment: Kafka topics were on a single partition, but this is good information for when I am looking to scale this out in the future, thank you.  David's answer was actually the solution to my problem.